# MATLAB error Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

im new to matlab and im writing a code to animate a grashof 4-bar mechanism.The code must run from zero to 360 degrees but stops after 2 iterations with the BELOW error. You help and suggestion is much appreciated , THANK YOU.
"Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1."

```
`a=1.6;
b=2.14;
c=2.06;
d=3.5;
AB=a
BC=b
CD=c
AD=d
xa=0;
ya=0;
yd=0;
xd=AD;





n=50;
t2=0

for ii=1:50
    syms t3 t4

    
    t2=t2+7.2
    f=a*cosd(t2) + b*cosd(t3) - c*cosd(t4) -3.5
    
    g=a*sind(t2) + b*sind(t3) - c*sind(t4)
    
    [t31, t41]=solve(f==0,g==0,t3,t4)
    
    th3=double(t31(t31>0))
    th4=double(t41(t41>0))

    
    xb=AB*cosd(t2);
    yb=AB*sind(t2);
    xc=xb  + BC*cosd(th3)
    yc=yb  + BC*sind(th3)


    
    plot(xa,ya,'k.',xb,yb,'b--.',xc,yc,'g--.',xd,yd,'c.',LineWidth=3)
    hold on
    
    axis equal
    line_plot1 = plot([xa,xb(ii)], [ya,yb(ii)], 'b',LineWidth=3);
    line_plot2 = plot([xb(ii),xc(ii)], [yb(ii),yc(ii)], 'r',LineWidth=3);
    line_plot3 = plot([xc(ii),xd], [yc(ii),yd], 'm',LineWidth=3);
    line_plot4 = plot([xd,xa(ii)], [yd,ya(ii)], 'c',LineWidth=3);
    axis equal
    
    hold off
    pause(0.06)
    `

    
end`
```

Comment: The variables `xb, yb, xc, yc` are scalar, but in the plot statements you try to access them as array (`xb(ii), yb(ii), xc(ii), yc(ii)`). From the second iteration onward you try to access, for example, `xb(2)`. I don't know the algorithm you want to implement, but, probably, `xb=AB*cosd(t2);` (and the other similar statements) should be `xb(ii)=AB*cosd(t2);`. The same happens to `xa, ya` that, by the way, are never evaluated

Comment: The problem is now fixed thanks